# Row Major Order Address calcuatlion

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I am calculating the index of an n dimensional array transformed to a flat 1d array.

```
    private int toFlatindex(int... dimensionIndices){
    int index = 0;

    for (int k = dimensionIndices.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {

        // Check if the specified index is within the bounds of the array
        if(dimensionIndices[k] < 0 || dimensionIndices[k] >= dimensionSizes[k]) {
            return -1;
        }

        // get the index in the flat array using the formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Address_calculation_in_general
        int start = 1;
        for (int l = dimensionSizes.length - 1; l >= k+1; l--) {
            start = start * dimensionSizes[l]; 
        }

        index += dimensionIndices[k]*start;
    }

    return index;
}
```

I have written this code which appears and tests correct. Although I have coded the formula from wikipedia I don't fully understand what is happening. I would appreciate someone explaining this, or even better linking a video tutorial/lecture on the address calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's work through the first few dimensions manually.

For a 1d array, which is a single row, element `[k]` is at position `k`.

For a 2d array, element `[j,k]` specifies the `k`'th element of row `j`. This is `k + start of row j`.  The start of row j is at `j * number of columns`. If the dimensions are listed in the array `dimensionSize`, then the number of columns is `dimensionSize[0]`.

Putting this together, element `[j,k]` is at `dimensionSize[0] * j + k`.

For a 3d array, element `[i,j,k]` specifies the `k`'th element of row `j` within "plane" `i` of the cube of elements. This is `k + start of row j in plane i`.  The start of row j in plane i is `i * size of plane + j * size of row`. Putting this together, element `[i,j,k]` is at

```
dimensionSize[0] * dimensionSize[1] * i + dimensionSize[0] * j + k.
```

Another way of writing this is

```
dimensionSize[0] * (dimensionSize[1] * i + j) + k.
```

The pattern is emerging. If we had a 4d array, element `[h,i,j,k]` would be

```
dimensionSize[0] * (dimensionSize[1] * (dimensionSize[2] * h + i) + j) + k
```

Now replace the indices k,j,i,h with an array `dimensionIndices[0..3]` and you should be able to see that function is doing this computation for an arbitrary number of dimensions.

A simpler coding would be:

```
int getOffset(int [] sizes, int [] indices) {
  int ofs = indices[sizes.length - 1];
  for (int d = sizes.length - 2; d >= 0; --d) {
    ofs = ofs * sizes[d] + indices[d];
  }
  return ofs;
}
```